# How to send XTZ from fundraiser wallet

Tags: baking

I purchased XTZ during the fundraiser and I have them in a paper wallet. I would like to bake with them but I need instructions on how to send them to an electronic wallet.

Comment: Both the singular and plural form is 'Tez'; not 'tezzie'

Answer (score 1):

If you have a paper wallet, then you should also have access to the private key of that wallet. All you need to do is import that private key into any online wallet (CLI, Kukai, Galleon, etc) and then you can delegate your tez from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the step-by-step instructions about how to activate your fundraiser wallet and how to send the XTZ to another wallet from this instruction page

https://tezos.com/get-started/#activate

This will involve:

- obtaining your activation code from the TF (if not done already)
- activating your allocation ( on https://activate.tezos.com/ )
- choose a software or hardware wallet and transferring to it

Galleon also offers video a tutorial about the process which you may find useful too

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eD-y1cEwB94